# My car keys are being “held” hostage after someone found them and removed the AirTag

Tags: theft-prevention

So I think I dropped my car keys in the laundry room of the apartment where I live, but fortunately enough, I have an AirTag attached to it, and for added peace of mind, I have a steering wheel lock, aka, the Club. Unfortunately, as it turns out I found only the AirTag discarded in the bushes somewhere without the keys. I rushed to check back to see if my car was still in the carport. Thank God it was there and not even stolen/broken into…yet.

I made a police report in case someone with my keys got any ideas to steal it before I even knew what had transpired.

I called Triple A twice in the middle of the night, they were no help.

First attempt, I wanted to have my car towed to my mother-in-law’s place just far enough from the potential car thief would be able to locate and steal my car. Keep in mind, not only do “they” have my key fob, but also, the key to the steering wheel lock itself. I’m baffled as to why they haven’t used that key to remove said lock if they were “smart” enough to remove the AirTag from the car keys.

The tow man couldn’t tow the car because of the steering wheel lock in place.

Second attempt, I called again after the police arrived for the report. The officer suggested to remove the battery. However, Triple A didn’t offer that service…atleast  not at night.

Perhaps they wanted to steal in the middle of the night like maybe 2 or 3am where everyone is dead asleep.

TLDR;

Lost keys that had airtag, found only airtag, no keys, car still in carport, steering wheel lock may have spooked them or not, Triple A no help. Hence, keys are being held “hostage” by someone who doesn’t have the intention of returning it to its rightful owner.

What can I do?? I feel like I’m in some kind of Catch-22 situation. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have spare keys?

Comment: AAA doesn't hold a nationwide monopoly on tow trucks. I'm sure if you called and hired a tow truck service yourself, somebody would come out and remove the battery for you.

Comment: Place the airtag in the car

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have theft insurance, at least for the time being until the following steps are completed:

Check with the dealer to purchase a new fob set and have the vehicle reprogrammed to refuse the old transmitter.

You will also need to replace the actual door lock and the ignition lock. This may be done by a qualified shop, not just the dealer.